# Are there any IoT devices with fully open source hardware?

Tags: raspberry-pi, banana-pi

Raspberry Pi is broadly used for IoT, and there is a lot of software for it. But I would like to know about any completely open source designs, including software and hardware (PCB, not components).

I have heard about [Banana Pi](http://www.bananapi.org/) but I'm not sure if it's completely open source or if other alternatives exist.

The main requirement is to be fully compatible with any of the broadly existing software platforms (Arduino, Raspberry Pi).

Of course, the components used in PCB should be available to anyone.

Comment: This is better asked on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and I think you should also try to define your requirements more clearly. For example, do you need GPU support, do you need Linux, or would a micropython platform be suitable for the application.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane ok. i'm going to reformulate

Comment: Please correct "BananaPi" both in the textbody and the tag. Thankx.

Comment: "components used in PCB should be available to anyone" lot of parts are unavailable in a lot of country, or you mean it should be available to individuals and not just companies?

Comment: This question is pretty opinion based, and broad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Postscapes IoT Hardware Guidebook](http://www.postscapes.com/internet-of-things-hardware/) lists quite a few:

- BeagleBone
- C.H.I.P.
- Dragino
- Espruino
- Flutter
- Hologram Dash
- Kinoma
- Libelium Waspmote
- Marvin
- Modulo
- Particle
- Seeeduino Cloud
- SODAQ Autonomo
- Spark Core
- Tessel 2
- Thunderboard Sense
- TinyDuino

Judging by the names, there are a few derivatives of the Arduino. Furthermore, all devices running Linux should be more or less compatible with the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Do you know online stores where I can buy these boards?
Particularly I am interested in the Waspmote and its sensor boards.

Answer (score 7):

I can strongly recommend the **particle** products! [Official website](https://www.particle.io/)

They are all **open source (Hardware and Software)** and there is a great community.

They offer the [particle photon](https://www.particle.io/products/hardware/photon-wifi-dev-kit) which is a wifi development board and the [particle electron](https://www.particle.io/products/hardware/electron-cellular-dev-kit), a cellular development board.

---

> The main requirement is to be fully compatible with any of the broadly
>   existing software platforms (Arduino, RaspberryPi)

Their newest feature is also to access the particle cloud from an RaspberryPi, which is currently in beta but already pretty cool. [Source](https://www.particle.io/products/development-tools/raspberry-pi-on-particle)

Comment: This is not really accurate.  If you dig into the details, you will find that these are only open source at high-level.  Key low level software components are closed source.  Some may be relatively available in binary form, but that still means they are not exposed to bugfixes other than through the vendor, which is a key tenant of open source.